# Import .cvs file into .mdf?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

How do I import a CVS file into a .MDF file in VS2010?  I can open and veiw the data for the .MDF file in VS2010 no problems.  When I try to connect with Excel, Import,Export (X64) tool, SQL Server Management Studio or Access I can't seem to get a connection to it.  they all seem to see the SQLEXPRESS server and not the MDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Stephan,
Do you mean a CSV file? (Comma separated data file)?
I don't know of any way to import a CSV file into an .MDF file.  Do you mean import a CSV file into a table within a database?
I can typically use the SQL Server Import/Export tool to import a CSV into a table within a database.  From there, you should be able to view/use the table in the database from Visual Studio.

Comment: yea think of it like you have Northwind.MDF and you have a CVS file that is formated just like the customer file, for import.  I can't seem to connect to the Northwind.MDF file with anything but vs2010.

Comment: The problem is connecting to the .MDF, What type of file is it?  SQL Server Native Client - doesn't get me to it. The .NET Framework Data provider for SqlServer - TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
------------------------------

The operation could not be completed.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Na

Comment: @StephanM You should check if your SQL Server is running.

Go to All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> SQL Server Services, and check if SQL Server service status is “Running”.

Comment: You cannot connect to a MDF file.  You have to connect to the SQL Server that is hosting that database.  Are you specifying your SQL Server hostname (or localhost if it's running on the same server) and providing a connection username and password?

Comment: @user1299241 I think stephan should post another question for this problem

Comment: @StephanM take a look at this http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: I will be re-posting a new question.

Comment: Thanks guys I reposted it and someone gave me a -2, WTH.

Comment: Figured it out, WIth win7 you have to give the user full Access to the directory where the MDF is.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a csv .text (can also be .csv) ,you can download it from [here](http://spatialnews.geocomm.com/newsletter/2000/jan/cenzuszipcodes.zip)

It has these fields,

Field 1 - State Fips Code 
Field 2 - 5-digit Zipcode 
Field 3 - State Abbreviation 
Field 4 - Zipcode Name 
Field 5 - Longitude in Decimal Degrees (West is assumed, no minus sign) 
Field 6 - Latitude in Decimal Degrees (North is assumed, no plus sign) 
Field 7 - 1990 Population (100%) 
Field 8 - Allocation Factor (decimal portion of state within zipcode)

**Example of file**
[image],

**Import Wizard**
[image]
First and very manual technique is the import wizard. This is great for ad-hoc and just to slam it in tasks.

In SSMS right click the database you want to import into. Scroll to Tasks and select Import Data…

For the data source we want out zips.txt file. Browse for it and select it. You should notice the wizard tries to fill in the blanks for you. One key thing here with this file I picked is there are “ “ qualifiers. So we need to make sure we add “ into the text qualifier field. The wizard will not do this for you.

[image]

Go through the remaining pages to view everything. No further changes should be needed though

[image]
[image]

Hit next after checking the pages out and select your destination. This in our case will be DBA.dbo.zips.

Following the destination step, go into the edit mappings section to ensure we look good on the types and counts.
[image]

Hit next and then finish. Once completed you will see the count of rows transferred and the success or failure rate

[image]
Import wizard completed and you have the data!

**P.S:** Solution derived from [Link](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/title-12)
Other Links:
[SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)